# SCSS generate prefix for class

Tags: sass

I want to be able to generate `.pre-class` and `.sub-class` for any `.class`.

e.g. `.title`, `.pre-title` and `.sub-title` or `.heading`, `.pre-heading`, `.sub-heading`

I can do this via passing class variable (example below), is there any cleaner/straightforward way to achieve prefixes for the class?

```
$className: heading;
.section {
  .#{$className} {
    color: pink;
  }
  .sub-#{$className} {
    color: red;
  }
  .pre-#{$className} {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[class^="sub-"] — starts with "status-" (obviously).

[class*=" sub-"] — contains the substring "status-" occurring directly after a space character. Class names are separated by whitespace per the HTML spec, hence the significant space character. This checks any other classes after the first if multiple classes are specified, and adds a bonus of checking the first class in case the attribute value is space-padded (which can happen with some applications that output class attributes dynamically).
```

Although the best way and my recommendation to reduce code/cleaning is what you mention. Definitely.

[Prefix SCSS here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/use-sass-variable-selector/)

Comment: This does not produce the same code as OP's, nor it has the same intention.

Answer (score 0):

You could use suffixes instead of prefixes.
It is shorter but less relevant.

```
$className: heading;

.section .#{$className} {
  color: pink;

  &-sub {
    color: red;
  }

  &-pre {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

Comment: for suffixes I dont need variable it is much easier, but I dont need suffixes.